# Porting vsftpd to Rust

Tags: c, rust, linker-errors

I'm porting a part of the vsftpd FTP server to Rust for my project. [vsftpd Homepage](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html)

I have rewritten the `opts.c` file as `opts.rs`, compiled it as a static rust library in object format as `opts.o`.

I have bundled all other `.o` files for the respective `.c` files as `CObject.o`. Now I'm trying to obtain the `vsftpd` executable using the Makefile as follows

`clang -o vsftpd CObject.o opts.o /usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-c78f872a5c746c09.so -Wl,-s -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now './vsf_findlibs.sh`

But I'm now getting the following linkage errors.

```
(.text.handle_opts+0x31): undefined reference to `str_upper(mystr*)'
(.text.handle_opts+0xbc): undefined reference to `str_equal_text(mystr const*, char const*)'
(.text.handle_opts+0x146): undefined reference to `vsf_cmdio_write(vsf_session*, int, char const*)'
(.text.handle_opts+0x1d1): undefined reference to `vsf_cmdio_write(vsf_session*, int, char const*)'
```

But `CObject.o` symbol table contains entries for all the above entries.
Output of `readelf -s CObject.o | grep -E '(str_upper|str_equal_text|vsf_cmdio_write)'` is

```
project@mylaptop:~/vsftpd-3.0.3-rustport$ readelf -s CObject.o | grep -E '(str_upper|str_equal_text|vsf_cmdio_write)'
 834: 0000000000000a30    54 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write
1004: 0000000000000a70    54 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write_hyphen
1061: 0000000000000b90    13 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write_str
1122: 0000000000000b10    97 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write_exit
1127: 0000000000000ab0    94 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write_raw
1211: 0000000000007df0    66 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 str_upper
1353: 0000000000007ca0    85 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 str_equal_text
1384: 0000000000000b80    13 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 vsf_cmdio_write_str_hyphe
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: `CObject.o` is a static library or a object file? Try to change the order of `.o` files.

Comment: `opts.c` is [this file](https://github.com/dagwieers/vsftpd/blob/master/opts.c)? Can you show what the new Rust versions looks like?

Comment: Note that your CObject.o has symbols such as `str_upper` while your error talks of `str_upper(mystr*)`, and those are not the same, maybe you are forgetting the `#[no_mangle]`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions guys, but the problem was with `rust bindgen` converting the `.h` files. It converted the function declaration from `void str_upper(struct mystr* p_str);` to `# [link_name = "\u{1}_Z9str_upperP5mystr"]  pub fn str_upper (p_str : *mut mystr) ;`. Then `clang` was trying to search for a function named `_Z9str_upperP5mystr`, causing the undefined reference error.

Comment: Removing the `#[link_name = "\u{1}_Z9str_upperP5mystr"]` part solved the problem.